# Escaping apostrophes in regex?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm trying to validate a form using a regular expression found here http://regexlib.com/. What I am trying to do is filter out all characters except a-z, commas and apostrophes. If I use this code:

```
<cfinput name="FirstName" type="text" class="fieldwidth" maxlength="90" required="yes"    validateat="onsubmit,onserver" message="Please ensure you give your First Name and it does not contain any special characters except hyphens or apostrophes." validate="regular_expression" pattern="^([a-zA-Z'-]+)$" />
```

I get the following error: Unmatched [] in expression. I figured out this relates to the apostrophe because it works if I use this code(but does not allow apostrophes):

```
<cfinput name="FirstName" type="text" class="fieldwidth" maxlength="90" required="yes"    validateat="onsubmit,onserver" message="Please ensure you give your First Name and it does not contain any special characters except hyphens or apostrophes." validate="regular_expression" pattern="^([a-zA-Z-]+)$" />
```

So I'm wondering is there some special way to escape apostrophes when using regular expressions?

EDIT

I think I've found where the problem is being caused (thanks to xanatos), not sure how to fix it. Basically CF is generating a hidden field to validate the field as follows:

```
<input type='hidden' name='FirstName_CFFORMREGEX' value='^([a-zA-Z'-]+)$'>
```

Because it is using single apostrophes rather than speech marks round the value, it is interpreting the apostrophe as the end of the value.

Comment: The apostrophe is a special character and needs to be escaped from the standard text by prefixing with '\', try pattern="^([a-zA-Z\'-]+)$"   HTH

Comment: @John Are you sure? And what does it means? How is it used in the Regex "language"?

Comment: I say 'try' so I'm not sure, regex has many flavours, and replacing tagged expressions is in fact absent from my Word 2002 program.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for that, unfortunately I'd already tried that and it did not work either.

Comment: @Kristian82 Try looking at the generated page with Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools and try to find the Regex and look at how it's written.

Comment: If `pattern="^[a-zA-Z\'-]+$"` isn't working, try `pattern="^[a-zA-Z\\'-]+$"` or `pattern="^[a-zA-Z''-]+$"`. Sometimes quotes can be escaped by doubling. (I also removed the unnecessary parentheses)

Comment: Thanks for those Tim, unfortunately I have the same problem with those two.

Comment: @Kristian82 If it's as writetn, it could be a bug of ColdFusion then, and probably you should report it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there is a bug in the cfinput implementation. It probably uses the string you pass in pattern in a Javascript Regex but it uses the `'` to quote it. So it converts it in:

```
new Regex('^([a-zA-Z'-]+)$')
```

Try replacing the quote with `\x27` (it's the code for the single quote)

Comment: Thanks for that xanato, unfortunately that does not work either. The Javascript validation actually works fine with my original but it's the server side validation where the problem is. If I don't get any further with this, I might just try write something to validate it on the server side myself.

Answer (score 0):

The unmatched ] is because the hyphen is treated to mean a range between the two characters around it.  Put the hyphen at the beginning as a best practice.

```
^([-a-zA-Z']+)$
```

Comment: Putting it to the end is the same good practice, no difference here.